# How to start using php 7.3 for Wordpress?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Wordpress advises me to start using php 7.3. I don't no how to arrange that. I have Wordpress running on Synology and have maria db 10 and Phpmyadmin installed.

I have installed php 7.2 and php 7.3 and at Webstation I have set php 7.2 as the general settings. But Phpmyadmin is still using php 5.6. And being a non-technical person I have no idea how to change that. I think I cannot. Does Phpmyadmin support php 7.2 or php 7.3 and if so, how can I upgrade to php 7.2 or php 7.3. Wordpress tells me that I am still on php 5.6

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/, there is no stable phpMyAdmin version that supports PHP 7.3. There is an alpha version of phpMyAdmin 5.0 that you can try, which supports PHP 7.1 and newer.